# mongooseJS with TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update data in a database by reading data from a file and using the 'update' method.

```
var Model = require('./dbIndex').Model

BioMetrics.update({AID: AID}, 
  {$pushAll: {
  attr1: data[5] === '' ? undefined : {val: data[5], dt: date},
  attr2: data[6] === '' ? undefined : {val: data[6], dt: date},
  attr3: data[10] === '' ? undefined : {val: data[10], dt: date}
 }}, options, callback);
```

When I run this I get the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined`

Mongo does not know what `undefined` means?  I had the impression that when undefined is true Mongo just ignores that attribute.

Can someone explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB may ignore fields set to `undefined`, but Mongoose doesn't as it has a schema to work from and will try and cast values to the right types as defined in the schema.

For a case like this you can build up your `$pushAll` value programmatically to only include the attributes you want:

```js
var value = {};
if (data[5] !== '') {
    value.attr1 = {val: data[5], dt: date};
}
if (data[6] !== '') {
    value.attr2 = {val: data[6], dt: date};
}
if (data[10] !== '') {
    value.attr3 = {val: data[10], dt: date};
}
BioMetrics.update({AID: AID}, {$pushAll: value}, options, callback);
```