# How to allow users to update their profile?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hey so I am trying to allow users to edit their profiles. However, some fields do not always exist in the document, unless they add the field. Here is how I am currently calling the query but I get an error if the field does not exist.

Here is the code for the routes file:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.signedCookies.userid,{
                firstName: req.body.firstName.toLowerCase(),
                lastName: req.body.lastName.toLowerCase(),
                email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
                firstNameTrue: req.body.firstName,
                lastNameTrue: req.body.lastName,
                emailTrue: req.body.email,
                emailList: req.body.newEmail, 
                phone: req.body.phone,
                phoneList: req.body.newphone,
                socialAccounts: {socialAccount: req.body.socialAccount, socialAddress: req.body.socialAccountNew},
                currentCity: req.body.currentCity,
                birthday: new Date(req.body.birthday) 
            }, function(err, user) {
                console.log('here1');
                if(err) {
                    console.log("post2");
                    console.log(err);
                    res.render('editUserProfileError', {title: 'Weblio'}); 
                } else {
            console.log("post3");
                    res.redirect('userProfile');
                }
            });

};
```

The error I am getting is :

```
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined]
```

I am using NodeJS with mongoose for mongodb. I have every field in the mongoose schema, but they are not saved in the db unless they are added manually by the users.

What I have tried but seems to be a big pain, to loop through all the fields value and see which ones exist, throw them in an array then query the array

Here is one solution I tried that is not working correctly since I need something to allow the ':' to pass through...

```
 var values = [
                firstNameVal =  req.body.firstName.toLowerCase(),
                lastNameVal =  req.body.lastName.toLowerCase(),
                emailVal =  req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
                firstNameTrueVal =  req.body.firstName,
                lastNameTrueVal =  req.body.lastName,
                emailTrueVal =  req.body.email,
                emailListVal =  req.body.newEmail, 
                phoneVal =  req.body.phone,
                phoneListVal =  req.body.newphone,
                currentCityVal =  req.body.currentCity,
                birthdayVal =  new Date(req.body.birthday)
        ];

        var  keyIcons = [
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            firstNameTrue,
            lastNameTrue,
            emailTrue,
            emailList, 
            phone,
            phoneList,
            currentCity,
            birthday
        ];

        var existValues =[];
        for(var x = 0; x <keyIcons.length; x++) {
            for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                if(values[i] === undefined) {
                    (console.log('undefined'))
                } else {
                    existValues.push({keyIcons[i] : values[i]});
                }
            };
        }

        var socialAccountsVal =  {socialAccount: req.body.socialAccount, socialAddress: req.body.socialAccountNew}
        if(socialAccountsVal.socialAccount === undefined) {

        } else {
            existValues.push(socialAccounts);
        };
```

Another solution I might be able to do is query the user doc and then see what values are available but I am actually confused about how to go about it...

Also, I feel lie there should be an easier way to do it?

EDIT

Here is my Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs'),
    SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;



var UserSchema = new Schema({ 
    email: { type: String, required: true, lowercase:true, index: { unique: true } }, //might have to take off lowercase
    emailTrue: { type: String},
    emailPrivate: {type: Boolean},
    emailList: {type: Array},
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    firstName: {type: String, lowercase:true, required: true, index: true},
    firstNameTrue: { type: String},
    lastName: {type: String, lowercase:true, required: true, index: true},
    lastNameTrue: { type: String},
    phone: {type: Number, required: true},
    phonePrivate: {type: Boolean},
    phoneList: {type: Array},
    birthday: {type: Date, required: true},
    birthdayPrivate: {type: Boolean},
    socialAccounts: {type: Array},
    currentCity: {type: String},
    date_created: {type: Date},
    email_confirmed: {type: Boolean},
    gender: {type: Number},
    currentDevice: {type: String},
    last_login: {type: Date}
}, {collection: "users"});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: What does your user Schema look like?

Comment: I added it to the bottom

Comment: See if the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904932/mongoosejs-with-typeerror-cannot-read-property-constructor-of-undefined) helps.

Comment: I do not think that is the same case as mine in terms of the how to solve it... if it is I am not sure I understand how to do that as the values are always random, and some are included while others arent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first construct an object with the fields in your `req`, and then pass that object to the mongoose method:

```
var userFields = {};
if (req.body.firstName) userFields.firstName = req.body.firstName.toLowerCase();
if (req.body.lastName) userFields.lastName = req.body.lastName.toLowerCase();
...etc...

User.findByAndUpdate(req.signedCookies.userid, userFields, function(err, user) {
    ...
});
```

This also allows you to do some sanitization of the fields in your request before passing them on to the database.

Comment: When the field is an array I usually check whether it has any items: `if (req.body.someArray && req.body.someArray.length > 0) userFields.someArray = req.body.someArray;`